# Почему зацикливается exception и как это исправить?

Tags: python, python-3.x, telebot

Пишу бота для скачивания и отправки картинок с сайта. Основная часть работает, но хотелось бы сделать предупреждение, о неправильно введенных данных ( то есть вместо чисел был введен текст). Попробовал сделать через exception, но оно зацикливает ответ `Цифрами, пожалуйста`. *Есть ощущение, будто изначально начал неправильно писать код.* Как можно это исправить?

```
import telebot
import requests
#bot = telebot.TeleBot("резерв токен")
bot = telebot.TeleBot("токен ._.")

lesson = 0
number = 0

@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])


def start(message):
    if message.text == '/start':
        bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, "Введи номер урока:")
        bot.register_next_step_handler(message, get_lesson)
    else:
        bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, 'Напиши /start')

def get_lesson(message): 
    global lesson
    while lesson == 0:
        try: 
            lesson = int(message.text)
        except ValueError:
            bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, 'Цифрами, пожалуйста')
            bot.register_next_step_handler(message, get_lesson)
    bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, 'Введи номер упражнения:')
    bot.register_next_step_handler(message, get_number) 

def get_number(message):
    global number
    number = int(message.text)
    bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, 'Начинаю качать...')
    url = 'sourceUrl' + str(lesson) + '/' + str(number) + '.jpg'
    r = requests.get(url)
    bot.send_photo(message.chat.id, r.content)

message = " "
bot.infinity_polling()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Цикл тут не нужен, используйте вместо него проверку и при `ValueError` выходите из функции:

```
def get_lesson(message): 
    global lesson
    if lesson == 0:
        try: 
            lesson = int(message.text)
        except ValueError:
            bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, 'Цифрами, пожалуйста')
            bot.register_next_step_handler(message, get_lesson)
            return

    bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, 'Введи номер упражнения:')
    bot.register_next_step_handler(message, get_number)
```

Comment: Да в таком случае и цикл не нужен

Comment: @mazzz3r, ага. Только что вспомнил о задаче, подумал о том же :)